# How to extend existing /root parition (ssd sata) with nvme ssd

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

I'm on /root which is filling up fast it uses ssd/sata based i want to expand with new ssd (nvme) is it a good idea to extend based upon two different hardware specs but one logical volume using Gparted, will it even work?

Comment: (1) You mentioned "logical volume". Do you use LVM? If not, do you use Btrfs? or Zfs? In general, what is the setup? (2) You mentioned "/root partition". Do you mean `/root` which happens to be a mountpoint in your case? Or do you mean "root filesystem" mounted at `/`. Clarifying this is probably not strictly necessary, but it may help avoid misunderstandings. // The (relevant parts of the) output of `lsblk` and `mount` may be a good reply to my both points. Please do not reply in comments, [edit] the question instead.